# jquery highcharts multiline mvc asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have a MVC application and would like to clarify some doubts of how to implement a graph with data from the database. 
I am using jquery to get the values ​​from the database, but did not understand how to catch these values ​​and generate a chart using Highcharts, I read a lot on internet but it was unclear how to get and put the values ​​on the x axis and the y axis.

For values ​​of x and y axes, I am using the following:

```
Dictionary <decimal, decimal> dataResult = new Dictionary <decimal, decimal> ();
```

Ai do the query on the database and ride as follows:

```
foreach (var item in query) 
{
     dataResult.Add (Convert.ToDecimal (item.valorinicial), Convert.ToDecimal (item.preco)); 

}
```

Pass the value:

```
return Json (dataResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To generate the graph:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function (evt) {
     //
     //Caught some variaiveis
     //

        var options = {
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: '#a2a2a1',
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 0,
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'area',
                plotBackgroundColor: '#fffdf6'
            },
            colors: ['#3399FF'],
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Graf'
            },
            tooltip: {
                borderRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '7pt',
                    color: '#000000'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value
                }
                },
                xAxis: {

                    labels: {
                        rotation: -45,
                        x: 0,
                        y: 40,
                        style: {
                            color: '#333333'
                        }
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#333333',
                    minPadding: 0,
                    maxPadding: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    tickInterval: 2,
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.value},
                        style: {
                            color: '#333333'
                        }
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#333333',
                    min: 0,
                    minPadding: 0,
                    maxPadding: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
                },
                series: [{ data: [] }]
            }
        jQuery.get("/ChartLev/GetByGraf", { ...some parameters....} },
            function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    options.series.data.push({
                        name: val.key,
                        y: val.Value
                    })

                });

                chart_answer = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
});
```

I do not know why the title appears only.

Comment: Any errors in javascript console? If not, could you attach JSON example? Also, first generate empty chart, then call `$.get()`

Answer (score 0):

Because you call addSeries, before you initialize chart, so you need to push this series into object like this scenario

```
  var options = {
       //chart options
       series: [{
            data:[]
        }]
    }

 $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        options.series.data.push({
                            name: val.key,
                            y: va.Value
                        })

                    });

chart_answer = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: Made as shown but not for generating the graph, Saberi tell me where I am going wrong.I'm putting the code in response to verify.